# HTML2PDF How to pass id to the html site to be converted

Tags: php, get, html2pdf

I´ve started using HTML2PDF (https://www.html2pdf.fr/) to create invoices, now the following code works:

```
try {
                ob_end_clean();
                ob_start();
                include('../faktura/fa.php');
                $html = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                $content = $html;

                $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'cs',true,"UTF-8");
                $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('freeserif');
                $html2pdf->pdf->SetFont('freeserif');
                $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
                $pdfContent = $html2pdf->output('my_doc.pdf', 'S');
                } catch (Html2PdfException $e) {
                $html2pdf->clean();
                $formatter = new ExceptionFormatter($e);
                echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
            }
```

The content of `fa.php` is converted to pdf, however if I change one of the lines to:

```
include('../faktura/fa.php?id=105');
```

note that I only added `?id=105`, it returns only a blank page.
The php file fa.php includes:

```
 $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

What I need to do is to pass an ID to that php script so the invoice of the exact order is generated.

Comment: you can not include a file like this include('../faktura/fa.php?id=105');

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan how can I include it with the id then?

Comment: you have to create a method in fa.php and use that method to pass your desired id and perform through it.

Comment: @MaiTruong and how can I pass the id from one php script to another that way? I am pretty new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include` basically means "copy the code from that file to here".

So if you change the included file code from $id = (int) $_GET['id']; to $id = $thatId;

And prior to the include() function you'd write $thatId = 105;
The included file will be able to access the variable.

**File A:**

```
$id = 105;
include('../faktura/fa.php');
```

**File fa.php**

```
    //$id = (int) $_GET['id']; // no need this anymore as we've declared a $id variable with a value;
    // .. Do something with $id
    // .. for example:
    echo $id; //will print 105
```

Or, in case you want fa.php to continue working with QUERY PARAMETER **and** to work with your invoice (2pdf) code:

```
if(!isset($id) && isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
}
```

Comment: I didn´t know include basically copies the code and I can use it´s variables, thank you very much for your answer. It works.